# Red Hat Virtual Box: Network is unreachable

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, redhat-enterprise-linux

I installed a RHEL virtual machine with Virtual Box and I can't ping my host computer nor internet.

I configured 2 adapters:

1. Attached to NAT, promiscuous allow all and cable connected
2. Atteched to Bridged Adapter, promiscuous allow all and cable connected

When I run `ip addr show`, here is the output:

[image: ip addr show output]

Thank you.

Comment: First of all, the eth0 has no IP address. So either it receives it from VirtualBox or you should assign it with some of the NAT IP segment (probably 192.168.x.x - you should be able to find it in virtualbox somewhere). The eth1 has no connection (virtual wire) as it says it has `NO-CARRIER` and is not in `LOWER_UP` state.

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications. Can I assign an ip adress to eth0?

Comment: Yes, from proper IP segment.

Answer (score 5):

Had similar issue

Check that you have following added to:
`/etc/sysconfig/network`:

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=my-hostname
```

Make sure you have configuration file in respective place (according to your device name):
`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3` in my case:

```
NAME=enp0s3
DEVICE=enp0s3
ONBOOT=yes
```

Then run:
`ifup enp0s3`
(your device name can be different, for example `eth0`, so double check that)

Also this command `sudo service networking restart` might help in some cases.

Related issue: https://serverfault.com/questions/660210/cant-start-centos-7-network-service

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jaroslav Kucera who said that I should assign an ip to eth0.

I followed this [article](http://www.aboutlinux.info/2005/01/how-to-assign-ip-address.html)

I modified /etc/sysconfig/network and /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 for DHCP then reboot.

Now I can ping internet.

Answer (score 1):

An additional contribution after chasing the very same complaint for two days:  I learned to look for the work " UP " in the NIC line and the br0 line (if present, as they are with virtual machines).  I use routinely for both CentOS 7 and RHEL 7 the commands:

```
# ip  link  set  br0  down
# ip  link  set  br0  up 
# systemctl  reboot
```

Verify the primary NICs have an " UP " status as well. They usually do.